# ASP.NET Core Blazor Hosted authentication over HTTP

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor

How can I configure `AddIdentityServerJwt` with HTTP. When running over HTTPS authentication works fine but over HTTP it fails.

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            services.AddDbContext<JDE_EDIContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("JDE_EDIConnection")));

            services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

            services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>();

            
            services.AddAuthentication()
                .AddIdentityServerJwt();

            services.Configure<JwtBearerOptions>(IdentityServerJwtConstants.IdentityServerJwtBearerScheme, options =>
            {
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                options.IncludeErrorDetails = true;

            });

            services.AddTransient<AppDbContextSeed>();

            //services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddControllersWithViews().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
                options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);
            services.AddRazorPages();
        }

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, AppDbContextSeed seeder)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
                app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            //app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();


            app.UseIdentityServer();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            seeder.SeedAdminUser();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
            });

        }
```

Comment: There are many tutorials and videos online, please search for them and try something first. If you are stuck in something please ask here with any code that you have tried.

Comment: Thanks @Umair for the update. That's the first thing I generally do! Below you can find what I tried so far:
             services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>();

            
            services.AddAuthentication()
                .AddIdentityServerJwt();

            services.Configure<JwtBearerOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            });

Comment: I would ask if this is for local development only? Any access to any secure resource should be made over https

Comment: Let's post all the content of `Startup.cs`

Comment: Thx for the updates! This is actually for deployment, and since the application will be deployed internally in an intranet site, this is just to avoid the hustle with self-singed certificates. The client doesn't have an AD to manage the certificates centrally, therefore the certificate will have to be installed manually on each client. Doable, I'm just trying to avoid!